# Limit sliderInput to a subrange

Tags: shiny

I have a `sliderInput()` ranging from **0 to 100** and would like to limit it to only allow values from 0 to 10. Is there a way to achieve that?

**Note:** This may seem like a silly request *(just set max = 10 to shorten the scale)* but it's for good reason I would like to maintain the full scale.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something link this:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui <-basicPage(
  sliderInput("slider1", "Slider 1: ", min = 0, max = 100, value = 0, step=1)
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  observeEvent(input$slider1,{
    if(input$slider1 > 10){
      updateSliderInput(session, "slider1", min = 0,max=100, value = 10)
    }
  })
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```